# What is the linguistic way to program matrices on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, matrix, data-structures

As simple as this should be, whenever I need to use matrices on Haskell, I struggle. My strategy is to chose a concrete type (REPA, Vector, List, IntMap, etc) and program for it. For example, I used REPA to solve Euler's [problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11), and I often use it on marathons. Unfortunately, REPA isn't a particularly friendly API - it requires complicate type annotations, thinking about the representation and tracking it, converting it around... also, indices are reversed. All that means I spend a good amount of time just looking at the docs and trying to align the types correctly, which is deadly when you are in a marathon.

I could just use vectors/lists, but that is, too, awkward, since then I need to use `toIndex :: [Int] → Int; fromIndex Int → [Int]` functions every time I index the vector.

I also tried creating a wrapper for Data.Vector such as `data Matrix a = Matrix { shape :: [a], buffer :: Vector a }`, but soon I noticed I also had to create a wrapper for every single vector function, and different types to match with mutable vectors and so on, and it was a mess.

In the end, all I need is a simple way to deal with matrices - something like:

```
matrix = Matrix.fromList [3,3] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
main = do
    matrix' <- set matrix [1,1] 0
    print $ get matrix [1,1]
    print $ sum matrix
```

Or anything else that lets me just think about matrices as mathematical objects and not a concrete implementation, but I failed to find a simple linguistic way. How would you do it? I wonder if Lens can help somehow?

Comment: The [linear](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.18.0.1/docs/Linear-Matrix.html) package has some generic matrix operations expressed in terms of a handful of generic typeclasses, but I don't understand it well enough to explain how it works off-hand.

Comment: If you want a simple "Matlab in Haskell" package, try [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) -- it has a pretty comprehensive and easy to understand API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You mean, really just matrices (i.e. arrays with two index-dimensions)? Then [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.1.5/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-HMatrix.html) is probably the best fit for you. Its matrix type is little different from your `Vector` wrapper, and its interface really feels a lot like “purely functional Matlab” (a philosophy I personally can't abide, but oh well...) at any rate, you get efficient linear-algebra operations, slicing etc. through underlying GSL routines. Mind, this library does not really do stateful stuff, it keeps a purely-functional interface and relies on the optimisations of the built-in routines.
- You mean, general multi-dimensional arrays / tensors, are more interested in element-wise operations rather than linear algebra, and need stateful updates? Then the good old [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array.html) library might be just right. It seems to have been somewhat eclipsed by `vector` and `repa` over the last years, but IMO, the `Data.Ix` indexing paradigm is actually pretty nice. Sort of a less mature, but also less “overengineered” version of `repa`.
- If you're actually *mostly* interested in linear algebra, then you should at least check out some of the more abstract libraries. I really like the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2) interface, which is very general and mathematical, it completely eschews writing operations in a particular basis, which does a lot to catch “mathematical bugs”.
- And while you mention `lens`es, there is the [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) – which is elegant and abstract in a different way. IMO it misses the point of linearity a bit (mathematically), but it's still pretty cool and definitely offers more operations than `vector-space`.
- Oh, and, finally, there's [matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-Matrix.html). It's quite of similar to `hmatrix`, but implemented in native Haskell rather than GSL bindings, which means that it's not so rich in highly-optimised LA algorithms, but also not such a heavy dependency. Apart from that, it appears to be slightly more elegant.

Comment: I really just want a N-dimensional **convenient** data structure. That is, one which I can create a 3D tilemap, copy/paste blocks, modify bounded volumes, zip, map, filter, etc. REPA is really fast but is cumbersome to use. Array is very bad too. I can't, for example, use Linear's vectors to index those arrays. That sucks... I don't think any of those answers does it. :(

Comment: Ah. Well, perhaps you shouldn't have asked for _matrices_ then... ...anyway, I think `array` is quite the right thing for your application, in particular you _can_ use `linear`'s `V` types to index them, since these have an `Ix` instance. What's your problem there?

Comment: No idea how I can create multidimensional arrays with V and index them with V3 for example.

Comment: Like, `array (V2 0 0,V2 1 1) [(V2 0 0,1),(V2 0 1,2),(V2 1 0,2),(V2 1 1,3)] ! V2 1 0`.